# React Native: SvgUri doesn't render SVG image from URL

Tags: react-native, svg

I am trying to load a logo from the response of an API in my app using the `react-native-svg` library. There are no errors of any kind, and when including the component in my code other elements of the screen are moving out of the way, there is just no visible image.

```
import { SvgUri } from "react-native-svg";

...


    <TouchableInfoContainer>
      <TouchableBar onPress={() => {}}>
        <SvgUri
          uri={data.operating_carrier.logo_symbol_url}
          height={20}
          width={20}
        />
        <DataText>
          {flightInfo[0].segments[0].operating_carrier.name}{" "}
          {flightInfo[0].segments[0].operating_carrier.iata_code}{" "}
          {flightInfo[0].segments[0].operating_carrier_flight_number}
        </DataText>
        <InfoSection>
          <Icon size={20} name="airplane-clock" color={theme.colors.white} />
          <DataText color={theme.colors.highlight}> 2:32</DataText>
        </InfoSection>
      </TouchableBar>
    </TouchableInfoContainer>
```

I've been following the documentation here: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg/blob/main/USAGE.md. I've attempted to install and use both `react-native-svg 13.4.0` and `react-native-svg 13.6.0` but neither work. I've also attempted to add a hardcoded link to an SVG file that I'm visited manually in my browser to ensure that it actually exists. No images will display, just blank space.

Comment: can you share your svg url?